# iis 10 rewrite module add request header

Tags: iis, http-headers, reverse-proxy, http-referer

I am new to IIS
try to use IIs AAR as reverse proxy and Rewrite Module to redirect the url
but the url i want redirect to  does not allow the blank referer, else get 403 forbidden
is there any way to add referer on the requesting header on IIS

windows server 2019
IIS 10

Answer (score 0):

I try to add referer on the requesting header by IIS server variables, but only in FailedReqLogFiles, I can see that the addition is successful, but not in the browser.

This is my tested:
[image]

**The result in the FailedReqLogFiles.**

[image]